# ¿Cómo abro chrome para poder probar una API en desarollo en App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome

sistema operativo: OS X El Capitan

Estoy corriendo una app en local utilizando App Engine en modo de desarollo en mi computador. Y quiero a través de chrome acceder al explorador de la API "localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer", pero me da un error porque chrome espera conexión https y mi app corriendo local sólo da http.

https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/#hitting_local_api
según este artículo la solución es:

[path-to-Chrome] --user-data-dir=test --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:port

ya he intentado correr cosas como:
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer

pero no logro hacer que funcione, me pregunto cual es la forma correcta de correr en la terminal para hacer que chrome corra en modo no seguro:

[path-to-Chrome] --user-data-dir=test --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:port

o si hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentas debido a actualizaciones de seguridad solo se puede lanzar el API habilitando el origen inseguro con el siguiente comando en la terminal:

```
/Applications/Google/Chrome.app --user-data-dir=RutaDeCarpetaConAccesoTotal --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:14080
```

Al lanzar chrome tiene dos parámetros:

> --user-data-dir

Que es la ruta donde se guardará la información temporal del usuario, debe ser una carpeta que se tenga acceso total (lectura y escritura)

> unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure

Que es donde se pone la dirección de tu aplicación que se habilitará, en en la mayoría de los casos es http://localhost:NumeroPuerto

Otra cosa que puedes hacer si no quieres realizar todos estos pasos es descargar una versión de chrome o probar tu API en otro navegador como por ejemplo Edge.

En Edge solo tienes que habilitar el contenido inseguro dando click en la imagen a la derecha de la dirección

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y dar click en la opción "Ver todo el contenido"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***UPDATE Ya vi que es OSX**

En Firefox el proceso es similar solo que la imagen donde hay que dar click esta a la izquierda de la dirección y en el tercer paso hay que dar click en la opción "Seguridad inhabilitada por ahora"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También tienes que tomar en cuenta que si hay un error en tu API no se mostrará, si usas el launcher, puedes ver el log para ver si existe algún error.

Comment: super gracias, esta es mi primera desilusion con chrome...